# Não consigo usar o onkeydown com precisão

Tags: javascript, script

tenho os seguintes campos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando eu informo o desconto em %, ele deve calcular automaticamente o Desconto em R$, e da o resultado no total liquido, e quando eu informo no Desconto R$, ele da o resultado em porcentagem no campo Desconto %, e o resultado no Total Liquido. Até ai beleza, to fazendo isso, mas o resultado só vai com precisão se eu aperta a tecla `TAB`, se eu não aperta a tecla `TAB`, os resultados não vem com as casas decimais certo, queria que ele fizesse isso, automaticamente, sem precisar pressionar nenhuma tecla, aonde o usuário, só em digitar o valor, ele desse os resultados certo.

Meus campos aonde contem o `onKeydown` e o `Script`:

```
     <input type="number" class="form-control desc_prc" id="Tot_desc_prc" desconto='tot_liquido' placeholder="%" onkeydown="DescontoPorcentagem()" step="00.00" min="0.00">

      <input type="number" class="form-control desc_vlr" id="Tot_desc_vlr" desconto='tot_liquido' placeholder="R$" onkeydown="DescontoReal()" step="00.00" min="0.00">

 <script>
     function DescontoPorcentagem() {
                var bruto = $("#tot_bruto").val();
                var porcentagem = $("#Tot_desc_prc").val();
                var real = $("#Tot_desc_vlr").val();
                var total;
                total = parseFloat((parseFloat(porcentagem) / 100) * parseFloat(bruto));

                $("#Tot_desc_vlr").val(parseFloat(total.toFixed(2)));
                total = parseFloat(bruto) - parseFloat(total);
                $("#tot_liquido").val(parseFloat(total.toFixed(2)));
            }

            function DescontoReal() {
                var bruto = $("#tot_bruto").val();
                var porcentagem = $("#Tot_desc_prc").val();
                var real = $("#Tot_desc_vlr").val();
                var total;
                total = parseFloat(bruto) - parseFloat(real)
                $("#tot_liquido").val(parseFloat(total.toFixed(2)));
                total = (real / bruto) * 100
               }
 </script>
```

Comment: Tem certeza que esse código é o suficiente para simular o problema?

Comment: É o que eu to usando no momento